# Access textview on another layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have made a popup, which works fine, but I'd like to write to the TextView on it. Using the standard method doesn't work (just crashes it), despite Eclipse finding the TextView's id and not showing any problems. The popup is in another XML layout.

Generates the popup

```
    public PopupWindow pw;

public void popUpShow() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
           this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    pw = new PopupWindow(
           inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null, false), 
           400, 
           600, 
           true);
            pw.showAtLocation(this.findViewById(R.id.main), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
}
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/popup_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#AAA"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/popupOut"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text=""
/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/popupclose"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/close"
    android:onClick="popUpHide" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you please add some code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before creating your PopupWindow, keep a reference to the view Inflated

```
ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null, false);

pw = new PopupWindow(
       v, 
       400, 
       600, 
       true);
        pw.showAtLocation(this.findViewById(R.id.main), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

TextView view = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the textView is in a dialog, then the view id should be retrieved by

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
TextView view = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Try

```
 public void popUpShow() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
           this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout t = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, null, false);
    PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(
           t, 
           400, 
           600, 
           true);

    pw.showAtLocation(t.findViewById(R.id.main), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
}
```